# ncurses & telnet protocol

Tags: telnet, ncurses

I'm working on program which exports a text user interface based on ncurses via telnet.
This basically works when I use hard coded values:

```
 fd = accept(sfd, NULL, 0); // tcp socket to client

 FILE *fh = fdopen(fd, "rw");

 SCREEN *scr = newterm("vt100", fh, fh);
 setterm(scr);
 resizeterm(25, 80);

 // ...regular ncurses code...
```

In ncurses you use getch() to retrieve key-presses. This will automatically convert special characters like cursor-key-up/down/etc (ESC [ A and such) to constants like KEY_UP.

Telnet uses special byte-codes to communicate parameters like terminal window size, terminal type etc to the telnet-client and vice versa.

If I want to get rid of these hard coded values, I would need to send the telnet codes but I would also need to receive their responses.

My question now is: will these telnet codes interfere with ncurses? Will I be able to use getch() or will getch misinterpret the ncurses codes for special characters?

Answer (score 3):

The place to start is with the RFCs: [RFC 854 - TELNET PROTOCOL SPECIFICATION](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) says that character `255` (`0xff`, the ***IAC***) is reserved for communication between client and server.

There's a disconnect between the RFC (theory) and practice (implementations).  The RFC is written with the obvious intention of supporting only simple teletype-replacements (i.e., no cursor addressing, no escape sequences at all).  From the standpoint of the RFC, once you start considering terminals (most of the available ones when the RFC was published in 1983 did support cursor addressing), there's not much to say except to be careful not to send an (unescaped) character `255`.

RFC 854 was updated (not obsoleted) by [RFC 5198 - Unicode Format for Network Interchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5198) in 2008.  Like RFC 854, it assumes that everyone uses a *glass teletype*, recommending that the backspace character not be used cause its behavior on different systems may differ.  The one useful comment in the RFC states that character 255 would not be part of a valid UTF-8 string.

If you were not using UTF-8, the ISO-8859-x encodings may send a 255.  It is a valid printable character.  ncurses would not send that character unless your data happens to include it, but ncurses has no special provision for escaping the character.

ncurses assumes that your communication path is 8-bit clean.  [RFC 856 - TELNET BINARY TRANSMISSION](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc856) addresses part of this, leaving the *Achilles heel* of the **IAC** untouched:

> *With the binary transmission option in effect, the receiver should
> interpret characters received from the transmitter which are not
> preceded with **`IAC`** as 8 bit binary data, with the exception of **`IAC`**
> followed by IAC which stands for the 8 bit binary data with the
> decimal value 255.*  **`IAC`** followed by an effective *TELNET* command (plus
> any additional characters required to complete the command) is still
> the command even with the binary transmission option in effect.  **`IAC`**
> followed by a character which is not a defined *TELNET* command has the
> same meaning as **`IAC`** followed by **`NOP`**, although an **`IAC`** followed by an
> undefined command should not normally be sent in this mode.

You may of course run into some implementation which is truly 8-bit clean, but it would not comply with the RFC.

Comment: To summarize: if I "run ncurses over a socket" and a telnet code passes by, then this will not confuse getch() and you will receive the telnet code as-is via getch(). Right?
Thanks a lot by the way!